# Не работает русский язык Java Glassfish

Tags: java, кодировка, post, java-ee, glassfish

Пишу бота для телеграмма, отправляю запрос на английском, прямиком из сервлета, чтобы потестить - всё работает. Как только хочу отправить сообщение на русском, оно отправляется в виде вопросительных знаков, т.е.

> Привет мир -> ?????? ???

Гугл не помог, всё делал, ничего не помогает :-(

**Использую**

- Galssfish 4
- Intellij Idea
- Maven
- CentOS 7
- Java EE 8

**Код Сервлета**

```
public class UITest extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* Setting consts */
        final String bottoken = "токен";
        final String channelId = "id_канала";
        final String params = "chat_id=" + channelId + "&" + "caption=" + "Test+test+test";
        final String url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bottoken + "/sendPhoto";

        /* Setting up builder */
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        /* Adding additional params */
        builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        builder.addTextBody("chat_id", channelId, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addTextBody("caption", "Проверка русских букв", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        /* Adding file part */
        File file = new File("/home/glassfish/test.png");
        builder.addBinaryBody(
                "photo",
                file,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                file.getName()
        );

        /* Building request */
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        /* Printing answer */
        resp.getWriter().println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseEntity.getContent())).readLine());
    }
}
```

**glassfish-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD
    GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
        "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>telegramtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegramtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Dependencies settings -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Validators -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build settings -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>telegramtest</warName>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Осталось только понять в какой кодировке вы отправляете (набиваете) *Привет мир* - очевидно в кодировке вашего IDE/консоли и опять таки очевидно, что кодировка IDE/консоли не UTF-8 (а должна быть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в get прописать req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
и + resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");